# What is the best guide to start developing Magento 2 modules?

Tags: magento2, module, development, resources

I'm starting to develop modules for Magento 2, but the main documentation seems a little confusing...

Since I know that are many experienced developers here, has come to me an idea to ask **what tutorials or articles did you follow to develop modules for Magento 2?** I know that are many blogs and websites (including StackExchange), but from your perspective, what helped you most?

Maybe some articles get a different perspective that can help to better understand some things on Magento 2... my question not just for me, but for everyone who is trying to increase their skills on Magento 2.

**You can cite articles from others languages too, it doesn't need to be only in English.**

Answer (score 5):

I Think, It will help you.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has helped me more than [Alan Storm's blog](https://alanstorm.com/series/magento-2-object-system/).

The series is eight parts which are all very crucial points to know about creating modules:

- [Object Manger](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager/)
- [Dependency Injection](https://alanstorm.com/magento2_dependency_injection_2015/)
- [Preferences](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences/)
- [Argument Replacement](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_argument_replacement/)
- [Virtual Types](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_virtual_types/)
- [Proxy Objects](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_proxy_objects/)
- [Instance Objects](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_instance_objects/)
- [Plugin System](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system/)

As far as a single tutorial, this would be my vote for the best resource I've come across. I read it when I first started Magento 2 and reference it frequently. [Alan Storm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4/alan-storm) is active on this site as well.